# How to open a form created on GWT using QRcode?

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a form that show details of a student (using GWT). I want to create a link of that form that should be opened using QR Code.

Comment: Go to [this website](http://goqr.me/#t=url) and paste in the URL of the page featuring your form.

Comment: i have no problem in generating QR code.Main problem is that how would i create the final URL of my form page using code.Actually i am working on a project that contains many forms. i want to open a particular form using QR Code. so how to make Final URL of that particular page

Comment: So actually your question is "how do I host a website"?

Comment: no sir.Actually i am working on a project that contains many forms. i want to open a particular form using QR Code. so how to make Final URL of that particular page

Comment: Are you using the History or Places API?

Comment: No i m not using history or places API

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: no. After making forms, i dnt know what to do to make final URL of that particular form

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need an URL to open a particular form.

First I suggest you to read documentation about [History Mechanism](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html). One of it's main feature is:

> It’s “bookmarkable”. I.e., the user can create a bookmark to the
>   current state and save it, email it, et cetera.

So you will be able to create a link to a specific application state. In your case a student form.

In the `EntryPoint` class, in `onModuleLoad()` method add this:

```
if(History.getToken() == "student_form")
    // show student form
else
    // proceed as normal
```

Now just add a history token at the end of yous normal URL (after a `#` sign) like this: http://host.com/#student_form or http://host.com/page.html#student_form.